# Ошибка при запросе к бд

Tags: python, база-данных

Пишу программу клиент-сервер. Данные пользователей сохраняются в базу данных.
Но при запуске программы клиента появляется ошибка, которая непонятно почему вообще появляется.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "client.py", line 3, in <module>
from database import *
File "D:\Socket\database.py", line 1, in <module>
import pymysql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

Код клиента:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from database import *

class Client():

def __init__(self):
    self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.client.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1234))

def listen_server(self):
    while True:
        data = self.client.recv(2048)
        if str(data) == 'ВОЙТИ':
            login = input('login:')
            password = input('password:')
            login, password = sign_in(self.client)

        print(data.decode('utf-8') + f' send by <{self.client}>')


def send_server(self):
    listen_thtead = Thread(target=client.listen_server, args=())
    listen_thtead.start()

    while True:
        self.client.send(input("-->").encode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Войдите в учетную запись или зарегиструйтесь')
    print('Для входа введите <ВОЙТИ>')
    print('Для регистрации введите <ЗАРЕГИСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ>')
    client = Client()
    client.send_server()
```

Код запроса к бд:

```
import pymysql
def sign_in(socket):


try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host="localhost",
        port=3306,
        user="root",
        password="soldan1512",
        database="chat_base",
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
    print("Successfully connected...")
    print("#" * 20)

    try:

        # insert data



        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            select_password = "SELECT password FROM registration_table WHERE socket = %s"
            cursor.execute(select_password, socket)
            rows_password = cursor.fetchall()
            rows_password = str(rows_password)
            rows_password = rows_password[15:-3]
            select_login = "SELECT login FROM registration_table WHERE socket = %s"
            cursor.execute(select_login, socket)
            rows_login = cursor.fetchall()
            rows_login = str(rows_login)
            rows_login = rows_login[12:-3]
            print("#" * 20)
            return rows_login, rows_password

    finally:
        connection.close()

except Exception as ex:
    print("Connection refused...")
    print(ex)
```

Comment: А вы вообще не забыли установить-то pymysql?

Comment: @andreymal  не забыл

Comment: Где и как вы его установили? Где и как вы запускаете свой код?

Comment: @andreymal установил и через пайчарм или через pip
запускаю через консоль

Comment: pycharm скорее всего использует виртуальное окружение (venv), значит и запускайте свой код тоже внутри виртуального окружения, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal как я запущу и сервер и клиент через пайчарм одновременно

Comment: Запускайте в консоли через созданное пайчармом виртуальное окружение

Comment: Можно в pycharm-е запустить сразу несколько приложений без проблем. Точно так же как запускаете по одному.